# Sull'origine di "per giunta" quale locuzione alternativa a "in aggiunta"

Tags: meaning, phrase-origin

Qual è l'origine di 'per giunta' così com'è usata da "B" nella seguente conversazione?

> A: "Con l'exit o con il default la Grecia ci impone, di fatto, una nuova tassa."
>
> B: "Invece le pensioni d'oro chi ce le impone? E, *per giunta*, c'è qualcuno che impone che i consiglieri regionali debbano guadagnare 200.000 € all'anno, a parte il successivo vitalizio?"

Comment: Why m'avete messo due downvotes?

Comment: I downvote non sono miei, ma immagino che sia perchè "giunta" ed "aggiunta" sono sinonimi in italiano, rendendo la domanda alquanto bizzarra...

Answer (score 2):

Deriva da ***[giunta](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/giunta1/)*** ossia  *l’atto dell’aggiungere, e più spesso concretamente, ciò che si aggiunge; aggiunta*. Come cita Treccani la locuzione era già in uso nel '300.

***Per giunta***:

> - ***Frequente la locuz. avv. per giunta, inoltre, per di più (di solito in senso irononico o in tono amaro)***:
>
>   - s’è fatto pagare bene, e per giunta ho dovuto ringraziarlo; sei un ingrato, e per g. ti fai beffe di me!;
>   - anticamente, con il signigicato proprio, anche ellitticamente giunta (senza cioè il per): *e avevasi un’oca a denaio e un papero giunta* (Boccaccio).

***In aggiunta***:

> - in aggiunta a quanto ho già comunicato, devo fare altre due precisazioni. Anche, ciò che si dà in più ***(v. giunta, che in questo significato è più comume)***.